# Accepting any JSon Format into WabApi (no Model)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

Normally when Writing my WebApi's the Json being passed in will have a consistent structure to it, so I'd map it directly onto a model in the form:

```
[Post]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> myWebApiMethod([FromBody] myModel Request)
```

this would be fine and work.

Now I need to code for Json input where there is not a common structure so I cant post against 'myModel'.

I thought that if I do something Like:

```
[Post]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> myWebApiMethod([FromBody] string Request)
```

would do the job of getting the Json over, but when I use Swagger, Request is empty. I also tried declaring as `HttpRequestMessage` but that also seemed to be empty.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use object as your parameter to bind for any JSON value. In C# an object is the base class for every other classes.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionMethord> MyActionMethod([FromBody] object anymodel)
{
    return Ok("Success");
}
```

Comment: Thanks dont know why I didn't try this, but this has done it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using generics for your API method definition? I use this for my async tasks with just a base model that has any common properties that all your API calls would have, it's not required though.

```
[Post]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> myWebApiMethod([FromBody] TReq request) 
where TResp : ResponseRptBase, new()
```

Comment: I couldn't even use generics because, the data that I am interested in could be wrapped in literally anything, and to any level.